# Need hint for string method

Tags: javascript, string

I'm making a prep course for a bootcamp - yes, n00b over here! - and I'm stuck in this particular exercise about *String Methods*

I need to manipulate this original string '**supercalifragilisticexpialidocious**' and obtain the following version: **docious-ali-expi-istic-fragil-cali-rupus**

I've tried this:

```
var bigWord = 'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious'; 
var newWord1 = bigWord.slice(27);
var newWord2 = bigWord.slice(24,27);
var newWord3 = bigWord.slice(20,24);
var newWord4 = bigWord.slice(15,20);
var newWord5 = bigWord.slice(9,15); 
var newWord6 = bigWord.slice(9,5);
var newWord7 = bigWord.slice(5,9);
var newWord8 = bigWord.charAt(4);
var newWord9 = bigWord.slice(1,2); 
var newWord10 = bigWord.charAt(2);
var newWord11 = bigWord.slice(32);
```

console.log(newWord1,newWord2,newWord3,newWord4,newWord5,newWord6,newWord7,newWord8,newWord9,newWord10,newWord11);

Does anybody have a hint for me? Can someone help me out?
Cheers!

Comment: I asume the desired output is `docious-ali-expi-istic-fragil-cali-repus` not 'docious-ali-expi-istic-fragil-cali-rupus'. If so please edit your question.

Comment: was about to say the same as @apena, is it repus or super ?

Comment: Will that always be the input? If so, it’s not a problem: return the correct output string.. I suspect the/a real problem is “more interesting”, such as applying some Pig Latin-esque transform.

Comment: If there is only one possible input, `supercalifragilisticexpialodicious`, you can hardcode your output...

Comment: @adao, would you please choose the answer you liked? Or give us hints, what you'd like to have corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code snipet that works. It does not answer your question though:

```
var bigWord = 'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious'; 
var newWord1 = bigWord.slice(27);
var newWord2 = bigWord.slice(24,27);
var newWord3 = bigWord.slice(20,24);
var newWord4 = bigWord.slice(15,20);
var newWord5 = bigWord.slice(9,15); 
var newWord6 = bigWord.slice(5,9);
var newWord7 = bigWord.charAt(4) + bigWord.slice(1,2) + bigWord.charAt(2) + bigWord.slice(32);
console.log([newWord1,newWord2,newWord3,newWord4,newWord5,newWord6,newWord7].join("-"));
```

The problems are:

- you used .slice(9,5) for word 6 which is incorrect, because 9 is behind the 5 and therefore newWord6 did not get the correct result, but "" (empty string)
- you did not add up word 7 to a whole, but printed its elements separately
- you have to print minus characters in between

  - either by putting + "-" + between every variables
  - or by adding up an array like mine and use the join() operator

Comment: Personally I would not use "newWordX" as variable names, because "new" is a keyword and it is easy to make typos and then searching for the problem the next hours...

Comment: thank you for you help and for pointing out the problems with my code. The .slice for some words were definitely wrong. Unfortunately, they (school) didn't want me to use the join operator but a much more simple (i think) approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for some Regexep stuff

```js
const original = 'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious';
const expected = 'docious-ali-expi-istic-fragil-cali-repus';

// the most common way to reverse a string is to explode it to an array and use the standard reverse method and then joining it back again as a string
function reverseString(str) {
    return str.split("").reverse().join("");
}

// the replacer method do the job of concataining words joining them by dash and call the reverse method for the last matched word.
function replacer(match, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, offset, string) {
  return [p7, p6, p5, p4, p3, p2, reverseString(p1)].join('-');
}

// pick the words by block of letters
const actual = original.replace(/(\w{5})(\w{4})(\w{6})(\w{5})(\w{4})(\w{3})(\w{7})/, replacer);

console.log(expected === actual);
```

Comment: I find this more cleaner than with the slice method, all that indexes made this so hard to read and debug ...

Comment: Of course, but if he does not even understand the mistake in those simple lines, I wouldn't go for more. But of course, your solution could be a valid solution too (didn't try).

Comment: Yes sure, it is maybe too hard for a newbie to understand Regexps

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make a simple example for you while keeping things somewhat dynamic so you can learn.
Assuming you want the words sliced from the end of the string to the start of it and then combined back together in reverse with a `-` then all you need to 'hardcode' is the length of each word to slice (from the start to the end) and then loop through that and slice out your words. So if you want to turn `supercalifragilisticexpialidocious` into `docious-ali-expi-istic-fragil-cali-super` you can do this:

```
var bigWord = 'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious';
var slices = [5, 4, 6, 5, 4, 3, 7];
var words = [], lastSlice = 0;
slices.forEach(slice => {
    words.push(bigWord.slice(lastSlice, lastSlice + slice))
    lastSlice += slice;
});
// Reverse the sliced words and join them back together with -
words = words.reverse().join('-');
console.log(words); // outputs docious-ali-expi-istic-fragil-cali-super
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var bigWord = 'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious'; 
var newWord1 = bigWord.slice(27);
var newWord2 = bigWord.slice(24,27);
var newWord3 = bigWord.slice(20,24);
var newWord4 = bigWord.slice(15,20);
var newWord5 = bigWord.slice(9,15);
var newWord6 = bigWord.slice(5,9);
var newWord7 = bigWord.charAt(4) + bigWord.slice(1,2) + bigWord.charAt(2) + bigWord.slice(32);

var newBigWord =(newWord1+'-'+newWord2+'-'+newWord3+'-'+newWord4+'-'+newWord5+'-'+newWord6+'-'+newWord7);

console.log(newBigWord);
```